How to use Column with AspectRatio?
I want to make a square widget that always stays a square but fill all the height and width available. It works.
Now I want to add a text above and below the text. The text above works fine. But I can't find a way to remove the huge space between the square and the text below.

Expected:

class LandingGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingGame({super.key});

  @override
  State<LandingGame> createState() => _LandingGameState();
}

class _LandingGameState extends State<LandingGame> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Expanded(child: _chessBoard(),),
                  Text("10:00"),
                  Expanded(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Row(
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          // _chessBoard
                          Expanded(child: _chessBoard()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("10:00"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Game Stats",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chessBoard() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Chess Board"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

As you can, it works on certain screen size, but it should work on any screen size.

Replace Expanded with Flexible in
class LandingGame extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingGame({super.key});

  @override
  State<LandingGame> createState() => _LandingGameState();
}

class _LandingGameState extends State<LandingGame> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Expanded(child: _chessBoard(),),
                  Text("10:00"),
/////// HERE 
                  Flexible(
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Row(
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          // _chessBoard
                          Expanded(child: _chessBoard()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("10:00"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Game Stats",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chessBoard() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 1,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center(
              child: Text("Chess Board"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

